# Hide form after get with php

Tags: php, html, forms

I got a newletter php form, so what I need is to hide the html input after the user click the submiting button, my code looks like this:

```
<form id="addressForm" action="index.php" method="get">
    <p id="foarm">
      <input type="text" name="address" id="address" placeholder="mail@example.com"/><br />
      <input type="submit" value="Notificame" id="gogo" />
    </p>
    <p id="response"><?php echo(storeAddress()); ?></p>
</form>
```

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: what do you want to hide? the submit button, the adress input box or the complete form? Are you using jquery?

Comment: Yes, i'm using jquery and I want to hide the adress field and the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use jquery to hide the form when the submit button is pressed.  Something like

```
$("form#addressForm").submit(function()
{
    $("form#addressForm").hide();
    return true;
}
```

Should do it.  You could do it without jquery, just using javascript - basically add an onclick event to change the css of the form to display:none when you click submit.  Id probably suggest placing it in a div section for ease.

Comment: Didn't work. The submit button refresh the page itself, I already try this method.

Comment: From memory return false; will prevent it